# Find 2x2 matrix such that its inverse equals its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find some matrix $B\in GL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ such that $B^{-1} = B^T$ and $B \neq I$

What I tried: I tried to create a simultaneous equation i.e. if B = $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$, then I equated the elements of the transpose to $\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}$$\begin{bmatrix} d&-b\\-c & a\end{bmatrix}$
but ended up with $ad-bc$ which doesn't make sense. What did I do wrong?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of matrices are called  [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) . There are many examples of them, notably the following rotation matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    cos(\theta)       & -sin(\theta) \\
    sin(\theta)       & cos(\theta)  \\
\end{bmatrix}
Note that this makes use that the determinant $cos^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta)$ will always be one. Furthermore, the adjoint of this matrix will equal the transpose.
Another example would be the identity matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}

I would like to note that these kind of matrices have many interesting properties. Notably, the set of all the rows or the set of all the columns will be a set of orthonormal vectors.

A 2x2 matrix will be orthogonal if the following criteria are met:

\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\
\end{bmatrix}

$$ 1 = a^2 + x^2 $$ 
$$ 1 = b^2 + c^2 $$ 
$$ 0 = ac + bd $$

There are indeed strategies of finding orthogonal matrices of higher dimensions.

Comment: Really nice solution . . . Thanks!

Comment: Besides the rotations (which include the identity matrix), the other 2x2 orthogonal matrices are the reflections, obtained (for example) by negating the second column in the arbitrary rotation matrix above.

Answer (score 2):

This is a better approach to solve the problem because it can easily generalized to a matrix in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$.

Let $B=(c_1\; c_2)$ the desired matrix where $c_i$ its $i$-column then we get

$$B^TB=(c_1\; c_2)^T(c_1\; c_2)=(c_1^T\; c_2^T)(c_1\; c_2)=\begin{pmatrix}c_1^Tc_1&c_1^Tc_2\\c_2^Tc_1&c_2^Tc_2\end{pmatrix}=I_2$$

which means that the columns of $B$ are orthonormal.